# How to find $\int\frac{\sqrt{(g/k)}(e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}-1)}{1+e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}}~dt$?

Tags: integration

I'm doing a physics problem and it boils down to finding this assuming my work is correct:

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{(g/k)}(e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}-1)}{1+e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}}~dt$$ to me this looks absolutely horrible to evaluate and was wondering if anyone here could help? Thanks.

$g,k$ are constants.

Comment: Why not just use Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Because it's from an old exam I will be taking. Hence no wolfram alpha will be available to me.

Comment: You can make it look a lot less horrible by writing $a=\sqrt{g/k}$ (say), assuming that $g,k$ don't depend on $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what work you did to get to this point, but we can solve this integral. Let $u = e^{t\sqrt{g/k}}$ which means  $dt = \frac{du}{u\sqrt{g/k}}$. Your integral can now be rewritten as $$\begin{align}\int\frac{\sqrt{(g/k)}(e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}-1)}{1+e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}}dt = \int\frac{\sqrt{(g/k)}(u^2-1)}{1+u^2} \cdot \frac{du}{u\sqrt{g/k}} \\ = \int\frac{u^2-1}{1+u^2} \cdot \frac{du}{u}\end{align}$$
**Hint:** With partial fraction decomposition you can show that $\frac{u^2-1}{u(1+u^2)} = 2\frac{u}{u^2+1}-\frac{1}{u}$, which means you could just write your integral as  $$\int\frac{u^2-1}{1+u^2} \cdot \frac{du}{u} = 2\int\frac{u\space du}{1+u^2} - \int\frac{du}{u}$$

Comment: No I cannot, also is what is the anti derivative for the first part?

Comment: $\int\frac{u}{1+u^2}du = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1+u^2\right|+C$. Try partial fraction decomposition on the remaining integral. I'll edit my post to include what I get from PFD as well.

Comment: Awesome I see it now and I'm confident I can now get the answer will give me something to work on later thanks!

Comment: I edited my post. PFD makes things *really* easy

Comment: Could you show me exactly how you used partial fraction here I don't see how you went from that step.

Comment: Given what's in the denominator, the equation you'll want to solve is $$\frac{u^2-1}{u(u^2+1)} = \frac{A}{u}+\frac{Bu+C}{u^2+1}$$ You should get $A=-1$ and $B = 2$. Do you know how to get to that point?

Comment: Got it thanks..

Comment: Happy to help :) Hope the rest of your studies go well.

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of $\sqrt{(g/k)}$ and replace it by a single term like $a$:
$$\int \frac{a(e^{2at} - 1)}{1 + e^{2at}} \, dt.$$

Now substitute, for example, $u = e^{2at}$. Then $du = 2au dt$ so you end up with
$$ \frac 12 \int \frac{u^2 - 1}{1 + u^2} \frac{1}{u} \, du.$$

Can you solve this one? Hint: you can simplify
$$ \frac{u^2 - 1}{u^2 + 1} \frac 1u = \frac{2u}{1 + u^2} - \frac 1u$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply top and bottom of the fraction in the integrand by $e^{-t\sqrt{g/k}}$, which gives
$$ \int \sqrt{g/k} \frac{e^{t\sqrt{g/k}}-e^{-t\sqrt{g/k}}}{e^{t\sqrt{g/k}}+e^{-t\sqrt{g/k}}} \, dt = \int \sqrt{g/k} \frac{\sinh{(t\sqrt{g/k})}}{\cosh{(t\sqrt{g/k})}} \, dt, $$
and then notice that
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \cosh{(t\sqrt{g/k})} = \sqrt{g/k} \sinh{(t\sqrt{g/k})}, $$
so the answer is
$$ \log{\cosh{(t\sqrt{g/k})}} + C $$